# Return View if table exists in database

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite, expo

I'm creating an app in React Native(expo).
The first time that the user is using the app will appear a  to choose the language that he want, when he choose one, the next time that he enter in the app no longer will appear.

Here is my code:

```
db.transaction(function (tx)  {    
//comando SQL modificável
tx.executeSql(
  "SELECT language FROM settings",
  [],
  (tx, results) => {       
    console.log("Results: " + results.rows.length) 
    if(results.rows.length == 0){
      console.log("Não tem nenhuma row")                        
    }
    else{
      console.log("tem uma row")                     
    }                    
  },      
  //-----------------------    
);
```

});

How can I  return a View inside of the first if() and return other  inside of the else.
Remember that if I return something inside of the db.transaction I will get one error that nothing was returned from render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe db.transaction is asynch so you may need to leverage a promise/delayed-return technique to return a View out of this block of code.

Here's a thought. Create a placeholder state variable that is injected into your component's view... and then later manipulate its contents to be whatever you want when your sql returns asynchronously.

Initially the jsx variable will be null and will basically not exist.. but after the promise returns, it'll be whatever Jsx you want (view, text, etc.).

You could slice and dice your view a lot of ways, but here's the basic approach. I just used Text's to keep things simple...

```
function someComponent(props) {

    let [ viewJsx, setViewJsx] = React.useState(null);
    
    db.transaction(function (tx)  {    
    //comando SQL modificável
    tx.executeSql(
      "SELECT language FROM settings",
      [],
      (tx, results) => {       
        console.log("Results: " + results.rows.length) 
        if(results.rows.length == 0){
          console.log("Não tem nenhuma row")                        
          setViewJsx(<Text>No row found</Text>);
        }
        else{
          console.log("tem uma row")                     
          setViewJsx(<Text>Found a row</Text>);
        }                    
      },      
      //-----------------------    
    );


  return (
   <View>
        <Text>This is my component. The next element will not show up until sqlLite promise transaction is complete..</Text>
        {viewJsx}
   </View>
  );


}
```